# I am trying to scrape but my command prompt prints nothing. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, request, screen-scraping, scrape

I am trying to print out headlines. Here is my code:

```
`import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base_url = 'http://www.nytimes.com'
r = requests.get(base_url)
r_html = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, features="lxml")

for story_heading in soup.find_all(class_="balancedHeadline"):
    if story_heading.a:
        print(story_heading.a.text.replace("\n", " ").strip())
    else:
        print(story_heading.contents[0].strip())`
```

My command prompt gives me no response. It prints nothing. What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list `soup.find_all(class_="balancedHeadline")` returns is empty. There seems to be no class "balancedHeadline". I didn't check the class scheme, but you'll get at least some results for `class_="css-1m5bs2v esl82me0"`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base_url = 'http://www.nytimes.com'
r = requests.get(base_url)
r_html = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)

for story_heading in soup.findAll(class_="css-1m5bs2v esl82me0"):
    print(story_heading.get_text())
```